# kendo numeric text box removes trailing zeros on focus

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a numeric text box with a value of 10.00.  When I focus back on the text box, the value becomes 10.  How can I keep the trailing zeros so when I focus on the text box, the value would be 10.00.

http://dojo.telerik.com/utUGA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`format("{0:n2}")` will force all input numbers to 2 decimal places. If you want to apply decimal places based on the value, use `format('0:0.##')` (where the number of decimal places (#) is the maximum number of decimal places you will have).

---

### EDIT

A [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/utUGA/14) example using my proposed solution.

Note: If you want to extend the number of decimal places available, modify the `format` to include another decimal place (`{0:0.###}`, `{0:0.####}` etc) and increase the `decimals` attribute to 3, 4 or however many you need.

### EDIT - Including trailing zero values on focus

[This example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eBevU/31) will keep the trailing zeros on focus of the numeric text box by binding a `focus` event on the element, and essentially rebuilding the value.

Comment: when you focus back on the number the decimals disappear. http://dojo.telerik.com/utUGA/12

Comment: You didn't use my proposed solution, you used a different one. I updated my answer with the appropriate dojo example.

Comment: In your example, if I change the value from 10 to 10.00, I focus out and then I focus back in the value stays 10.  I want the value to be 10.00.  that was my original problem.  Sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Check the new example which will keep the trailing zeros when focusing into the numeric text box

Comment: thanks, my original approach was to bind to the focus event and was looking to avoid it but I guess its the only way.

Comment: I was also trying to avoid this "manual" setting on the event, but it worked quite well, I do agree with Lun Zhan, it might be the only way. +1

Answer (score 2):

Add this [`format`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#configuration-format) property to configuration.

```
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
    decimals: 2,
    format: '#.##'
});
```

[Kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/utUGA/7)

Comment: You could use `format: 'n2'`, which will display two decimal places

Comment: I did use 'n2' but when you focus back on the number, the 10.00 becomes 10